# Mount Windows share automatically with Active Directory credentials

Tags: macos, smb, active-directory, automount

In our environment we have a bunch of iMacs running Mountain Lion that are bound to Active Directory for authentication, and we also have a Windows share that we would like all Active Directory authenticated users to be able to access.  The share is setup so that all members of the "Authenticated Users" group has read access to the share.

So far, all of our Windows computers are working exactly as we want because (from what I understand) Windows automatically sends the NTLM credentials when connecting to a share.  We'd like the experience to be the same on our iMacs (i.e., we don't want the user to have to enter their AD credentials again after logging in).  We'd like the user to be able to just connect to the server and view the folder or be able to access the shared folder from a script without using a pass-through account.

Any thoughts?